# File size of a PNG image created with data URL?

Tags: php, png, filesize

Can I safely assume that the size (in bytes) of a PNG image file created with the following PHP code:

```
$f = fopen("newImageFile.png", 'w');
$content = base64_decode(substr($dataURL, strpos($dataURL, ',') + 1));
fwrite($f, $content);
```

where `$dataURL` is posted from HTML's `canves.toDataURL()`, exactly equals `strlen($content)`?

Comment: Given that "[strlen() returns the number of bytes rather than the number of characters in a string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php)", I think that's a reasonable method to find the data length. I'm not sure how the file size would differ, but I'm not completely certain on that, so I'm not going to make this an answer, though :) I'd definitely open your file with "wb", though, rather than just "w", as you're writing binary data.

Comment: Thank you. I really didn't know I should use the "wb" mode when writing binary data. I've just reread the documentation, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `getimagesizefromstring()` If you have a newer php version.

But since you are decoding you could use this as well.

```
    $uri = 'data://application/octet-stream;base64,' . base64_encode($data);
    getimagesize($uri);
```